# Docker redirect port inside container or multiple containers with same port and network_mode

Tags: docker, docker-compose, port, vpn, iptables

I'm looking for a way to either redirect ports within a container (Not using Docker with '-p') or use multiple containers with same port with network_mode.

Background:
I have a service (VPN) inside a container that provides a central gateway to another network. Now I want to use "network_mode: 'container:vpn'" to attach additional 'sub'-containers to the VPN container so that they also use the corresponding VPN. This also works. To be able to access services I have to pass ports of the sub-containers to the host, which has to be done via the VPN container (works also). But here I have a problem, if several sub-containers publish the same port, I do not know how to map them, because for example the port 8000 is used multiple times.

The port in the original images I can't adjust because the applications need this internally or can not allocate it differently. Now I had the idea to use the containers as base image and to create a shadow image in which the ports are redirected by iptables (`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8020`). However, this doesn't seem to work because iptables can't be used in a container (only in privileged mode which I don't want).

I wonder how to solve this problem?
Maybe someone has an idea what methods/options there are to solve the problem.
Ideally, I would like to continue using different docker-compose files for every service.
thx

Answer (score 1):

Install socat in the docker image you want to do the port forwarding

for example add this to your Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get install -y socat
```

The command to install socat could be different for other os variants.

Once socat is installed, just call it.
In this example it redirects from 7545 to 8545 in the same container

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:7545 TCP4:127.0.0.1:8545
```